# Call function on part of a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to call a function on a part of a dataframe. 
For example my dataframe is like this:

```
 name var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 ... varN
 a     1    1    1     3    3  ...   3
 b     1    1    1     3    3        3
 c     1    1    1     3    3        3
 d     1    1    1     3    3        3
 e     1    1    1     3    3  ...   3
```

how can I call a function from var4 to varN in each row? like adding 2 for each 3? and "adding 2" can be replaced by any other functions

```
 name var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 ... varN
 a     1    1    1     5    5  ...   5
 b     1    1    1     5    5        5
 c     1    1    1     5    5   ...  5
 d     1    1    1     5    5        5
 e     1    1    1     5    5        5
```

Comment: `df[6:(N + 1)] <-  df[6:(N + 1)] + 2`?

Comment: Something like: `add2 <- function(x) x + 2; df[5:6] <- lapply(df[5:6], add2)` maybe?